# Как зашифровать бинарный файл в текстовый?

Tags: c#

Подскажите мне нужно зашифровать файл `.exe` чтобы он был зашифрован и имел текстовый формат `.txt` какими алгоритмами можно это реализовать?
И чтобы можно было обратно расшифровать с `.txt` в `.exe` без потери байтов!

Comment: Просто измените расширение.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Мне нужно именно зашифровать

Comment: Изменяете расширение у файла на `.txt` и любым алгоритмом шифрования без потерь (в гугле вбейте и найдете) шифруете `.txt` файл, а потом просто дешифруете и изменяете расширение.

Comment: А зачем именно текстовый? В чем именно заключается задача?

Comment: [Пример шифрования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1213972/373567). Можете вывод еще дополнительно в Base64 преобразовать, и получится текстовый файл по содержимому.

Comment: Вопрос непонятен, но похоже, что топикстартер хочет чтобы зашифрованный файл можно было открывать в блокноте и редактировать (не спрашивайте меня зачем). Если так, то можно зашифровать любым алгоритмом, а потом поверх в base64

Comment: @AK редактировать как текстовый - это круто, но любое изменение любого байта просто сделает невозможным его расшифровать. А так, в целом похоже на попытку обмануть антивирус или что-то типа этого.

Comment: Можно ещё вспомнить стеганографию. В реальный текст можно спрятать секретные данные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В .NET уже есть готовые методы шифрования - [AES](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=net-5.0). Дополнительно зашифрованный файл можно перевести в base64 и зашифровать повторно.

**Рекомендации**

Для проверки целостности файлов принято сравнивать контрольные суммы (добавочный хэш) шифруемого файла и расшифрованного, и если хэши совпадают, смело сохранять полученный зашифрованный файл и удалять оригинал.